# Convert Matlab timestamp data to seconds (HH:MM:SS:TTT -> seconds)

Tags: matlab, time

My data (cell) in Matlab looks like this:

```
00.00.00.515
00.00.00.671
00.00.00.828
00.00.00.984
00.00.01.140
etc.
```

This is the time stamp: HH:MM:SS:TTT, the T stands for thousandth (=milliseconds). The milliseconds are important because the step size is small. How to convert this data (cell) to data Matlab can handle (double)?
So the data will be as follow:

```
0.515
0.671
0.828
0.984
1.140
etc.
```

The minutes and hours should be converted to seconds so it is easy to calculate the total time of the data or the average stepsize. So:

```
01.30.00.000
```

will be:

```
5400.000
```

seconds

Thanks!

Comment: What have yout tried so far? Have you looked at datenum, or datetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your cell array contains strings:

```
ts = {'00.00.00.515'
      '00.00.00.671'
      '00.00.00.828'
      '00.00.00.984'
      '00.00.01.140'};
```

it can be done as follows:

```
>> cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) sscanf(c,'%d.%d.%f').', ts, 'uniformout', 0)) * [3600 60 1].'
ans =
    0.5150
    0.6710
    0.8280
    0.9840
    1.1400
```

This uses [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to convert each cell into a row vector of numbers with [`sscanf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html),; then concatenates all those vectos into a matrix with [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html); and fianlly applies matrix multiplication to compute time.

The code also works if the number of digits is not fixed. For example:

```
>> ts = {'0.1.00.51'};
>> cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) sscanf(c,'%d.%d.%f').', ts, 'uniformout', 0)) * [3600 60 1].'
ans =
   60.5100
```

Comment: Suppose the data is seperated by : instead of . Is it possible to convert this in Matlab or it is possible to edit the code you wrote? Because the code doesn't work if the data is seperated by :.

Comment: @WillemRoovers Try replacing `'%d.%d.%f'` by `'%d:%d:%f'`

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work. But I found another way to work around this problem. Thanks anyway!